# Not getting Write permissions in firebase firestore : PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting the Error

> [WriteStream]: (f4709b1) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.
> W/Firestore( 9128): (24.7.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/TnjVEXoWVxP4WLEfd2kNtoI65NNR: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
> I/flutter ( 9128): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

for the below code statement

```
 var user = UserModel(
          name: name,
          uid: uid,
          profilePic: photoUrl,
          isOnline: true,
          phoneNumber: auth.currentUser!.phoneNumber!,
          groupId: []);
     
 await firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).set(user.toMap()).then(
        (value) {
          print("successfully created a user ");
        },
      );
```

and my security rules are like this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo thats only member-only blog!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your rules looks correct. You should give more details.
Also you can try read and write permissions like this. Ensure you puslish the new rules when you changed it.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read
      allow write
    }
  }
}
```